# Grant privileges on tables in other database

Tags: postgresql

**Context**

I want to grant privileges to a specific user, on the `public` schema in database `mydb`.

Currently, I connect as user `postgres` on database `mydb`, and run :

```
GRANT insert, update, delete, truncate ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO myuser
```

**My Issue**

I would feel more comfortable naming the target database *in the query*, rather than relying on the connection being on the correct database.

For example, I wouldn't want to accidentally give accesses on the `postgres` database, rather than on `mydb`.

**Question**

Is there a way to target tables *in another database* in a `GRANT` query ?

I couldn't find a way to do so in the doc (perhaps I overlooked a paragraph ?) and the following do not work :

```
# grant insert on all tables in schema mydb.public to myuser;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "."
LINE 1: grant insert on all tables in schema mydb.public to...
                                                          ^
# grant insert on mydb.public.mytable1 to myuser;
ERROR:  cross-database references are not implemented: "mydb.public.mytable1"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, as the error message says, cross-database references are not implemented.

This is a security feature: There is no way to affect another database than the one you are connected to with an SQL statement (unless you are using something like dblink or foreign data wrappers).